# SwiftUI TabView Animation

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

I am currently facing a pb on my app.
I would like to animate the insertion and removal of items that are controlled by SwiftUI TabView.

Here is a simple view to reproduce the problem

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection.animation(),
                content:  {
                    Text("Tab Content 1")
                        .transition(.slide) //could be anything this is for example
                        .tabItem { Text("tab1") }.tag(1)
                        .onAppear() {print("testApp")}
                        .onDisappear(){print("testDis")}
                    Text("Tab Content 2")
                        .transition(.slide)
                        .tabItem { Text("tab2") }.tag(2)
                })
       
    }
}
```

When hitting a tabItem, it switches instantly from  "Tab Content 1" to "Tab Content 2" and I would like to animate it (not the tab item button the actual tab content). The `onAppear` and `onDisapear` are called as expected hence all transition should be triggered.

If someone has an idea to start working with I would be very happy

Thanks

Comment: Sry. I was over a ton of work recently and this particular problem was way low on my priorities. I did test it rapidly and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.with `.transition()` we only specify which transition should happen.

2.Transition occur (as expected), only when explicit animation occurs.

3.Animation occurs when change happened(State, Binding)

*here is one of possible approaches.*

```swift
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var selection: Int = 1
        var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $selection,
                    content:  {
                        ItemView(text:"1")
                            .tabItem { Text("tab1") }.tag(1)
                        ItemView(text: "2")
                            .tabItem { Text("tab2") }.tag(2)
                    })
            
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ItemView: View {
        let text: String
        @State var hidden = true
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if !hidden {
                    Text("Tab Content " + text)
                        .transition(.slide) 
                }
            }
            .onAppear() { withAnimation {
                hidden = false
            }}
            .onDisappear(){hidden = true}
            
        }
    }
```